# Set a value at the top level of a Firebase db with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

How can I set a value at the top level of a Firebase db with React.

A tutorial (behind a paywall) explains setting a value in a sub-record, but I haven't figured out how to do it at the top-level.

**Updating a sub-record:**

```
componentDidMount: function() {
  this.ref = new Firebase('<url>');
  var childRef = this.ref.child(this.props.params.username);
  this.bindAsArray(childRef, 'notes');
},
handleAddNote: function(newNote) {
  this.ref.child(this.props.params.username)
     .child(this.state.notes.length).set(newNote);
}...
```

Trying to do something like below, but not sure how to get the length of items at the top level.

```
componentDidMount: function() {
  this.ref = new Firebase('<url>');
  this.bindAsArray(this.ref, 'notes');
},
handleAddNote: function(newNote) {
  this.ref.child(this.state.notes.length).set(newNote);
}...
```

I started React a couple days ago so any advice would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

It previously wasn't working due to counting the length of elements for a specific state that had no elements, so overwriting the first item (0 index) in the Firebase db each time something was added.

**This worked:**

```
componentDidMount: function() {
  this.ref = new Firebase('<url>');
  this.bindAsArray(this.ref, 'notes');
},
handleAddNote: function(newNote) {
  this.ref.child(this.state.notes.length).set(newNote);
},
```